# function with $f=\hat{f}$

Tags: fourier-transform

Is there a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ with $\hat{f}=f$? It is trivial that $f=\hat{f}$ for $f=0$ but is there another function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Eigenfunctions

Comment: Try $g+\mathcal{F}[g]+\mathcal{F}^2[g]+\mathcal{F}^3[g]$.  Also it depends on the normalization, $0$ is the only solution with $\mathcal{F}[g]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx$

Comment: See this for an explanation and a list  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12045/what-are-fixed-points-of-the-fourier-transform

Comment: Take the Gaussian...